# Python in operator doesn't work

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm checking if a zip code value exists in the list using *in* operator.
However "in" check fails, although the value does exist in the list:

```
def scrapForZipVsState():
    existingZipsDF = pd.read_csv("crosswalk.csv", error_bad_lines=False, sep=";", header=None, usecols=[0,1])

    existingZips = list(existingZipsDF[0])
    print(existingZips)
    for zp in zips: 
        cleanZip = str(zp).split('-', 1)[0]
        print(cleanZip)
        if str(cleanZip) in list(existingZips):
            print("Skipping...")
            continue
```

And the log is:

```
[94163, 28255, 94163, 28255, 10017, 94163, 28255, 10017, 78288, 15129, 23285, 94163]
94163
...
```

What might be an issue here? thanks

Comment: It looks like you're searching for a string in a list of integers.

Comment: I agree with Bryan Oakley, you should convert your cleanZip to a integer

Comment: `cleanZip` is definitely a string, and your print suggests you have *integers* in the list. `in` works by testing for equality, and `'94163' == 94163` is false, strings are not equal to integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values in the list are integers, you're checking for the containment of a string:

```
if str(cleanZip) in list(existingZips):
#  ^^^
    ...
```

You should do:

```
if int(cleanZip) in list(existingZips):
    ...
```